# Image navigation: usability + google search

Tags: image

I have the following problem:

I want to use images for my navigation, because I want to use a special font (Meta).
I know that images for navigation suck very much, so I am wondering what the best way to build such a navigation would be.

I have 2 main concerns:

1. Google findability.
2. Usability.

It is for my design portfolio so I am not overly concerned with screen readers (not much sense in my opinion, since it is all about designs in any case).

Is it better to use real images ( incl. alt tags) or should I just hide the text using a negative text-indent and use a css background image. Maybe there is even a third and better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images with alt text will be fine for web spiders, but not ideal for usability (you can't search a page for alt text in most browsers). Negative text indents are searchable, but the highlight won't be visible and IMO that's actually worse.

The best solution is to use a [web font](http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/) instead of images. You can generate one from your desktop font easily with [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Comment: Thanks. Well, web fonts are just to slow, because they involve javascript stuff. I Just need it for 5 navigation points so images are the faster way here.

Comment: Web fonts have nothing to do with JS. See the "Using @font-face" of the first link I posted for how easy they are to use.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, did see it, but my font is bought, so it is not legal for usage with web fonts, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Check your license.